# How to create collection in ORMLite without using annotations?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

How can I create collection OneToMany without using annotations?

Now I'm using DatabaseFieldConfig like this:

```
DatabaseFieldConfig collection = new DatabaseFieldConfig("name");
collection.setForeignCollection(true);
```

But it doesn't work because I always get "Not fields has DatabaseField annotation" when I'm trying to create Dao.

Below is my example code:

```
public class HasCollection {
    private long id;
    private Collection<CollElement> coll;

    ...
}
public class CollElement {
    private long id;
    private HasCollection parent;

    ...
}
```

When I'm creating DAO for HasCollection I get error that "Not fields has DatabaseField annotation in CollElement" and if I'm creating DAO for CollElement I get error "Not fields has DatabaseField annotation in HasCollection"

Comment: Why do you want to avoid annotations? Annotations are crucial for framework to know how to manage class fields.

Comment: I cannot edit this files to add annotations. There are in other project.

Comment: Can you extend a model class based on the external class?

Comment: Yes I can but how it would help me?

Comment: You would annotate fields of extended class and use them with ormlite.

Comment: Could you write example with HasCollection and CollElement classes?

Comment: You certainly should be able to programmatically build the config.  Can you put your entire entity config code up in http://pastebin.com  or something?

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample code when extending class but it would drag dependency on ormlite DAO into this extended model class which is definitly not the right pattern.

Therefore in this case I would consider the class from another project as a DTO (data transfer object) and I would create another model class with annotations for ormlite.

Than made a simple convertor from DTO to the model class and vice versa used in layer where you want to persist objects.